# Problems with installing and using scikit-learn in Anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I installed Anaconda on 64bit windows and I also installed scikit-learn using "conda install scikit-learn". However I can't find scikit-learn when I print out all modules installed in python, and I can't import scikit-learn. So I guess the package wasn't installed correctly.

But if I do "conda update scikit-learn", it will print "all reuqested packages already installed. Packages in environment at ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda:"
Scikit-learn 0.15.2 np19py27_0

Any suggestions on what might have gone wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you make the import ?

Comment: i didn't import. I launched a command window, type "python", then in "help()", call "modules"

Comment: @user2502206, so if you type `import sklearn` you get an `ImportError`?

Comment: yes, I get a syntax error. File "<ipython-input-3-0f8874ae07c9>", line 1
    pip install scikit-learn
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: OK I figured it out. I typed "import scikit-learn" instead of "import sklearn". Thanks all!

Comment: import sklearn as sk works just fine

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in the comments, you import the scikit-learn module using:

```
import sklearn
```

Answer (score 0):

If it still does not work then try to activate environment which is by default root, if you have not created separate environment while installing.

Just run from cmd : `activate {env_name}`

For your case, it would be : `activate root`
then run simple python file to check scikit-learn is imported or not.

demo.py

import sklearn

See output in image below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMido.png)