# scikit-learn already insalled using mininaconda but import sklearn doesn't find the module

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, miniconda

I have already installed numpy, scipy, matplotlib, nltk, scikit-learn using
     **conda install module_name** in  *miniconda*. And import- numpy, scipy are working. but  when I do *import sklearn* and  *import nltk* it says that no module named sklearn and same in case of nltk. [sklearn import error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxWl2.png)

I have already seen many similar problems here. some of are:
1). [Problems with installing and using scikit-learn in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045176/problems-with-installing-and-using-scikit-learn-in-anaconda)
2).[Cannot import scikits-learn even though it seems to be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212987/cannot-import-scikits-learn-even-though-it-seems-to-be-installed)
 But could not get any help.
please help.

Comment: Why are you hanging out in the deep nested environment folders of anaconda (it's not supposed to be used like that)? Just use [activate](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate) to put the right environment into path (and if needed: do the install while activated).

Comment: @sascha  thank you so much, installing while activated environment worked. :) . Please tell me how do I run a python file e.g startup.py ? The files has all the modules specified up in the problem.I am new to  python.

Comment: ```python startup.py``` while the environment is active. Consider reading some python tutorials!

Comment: @sascha Thank you :)

Comment: @sascha would you help me installing the module cPickle?   coda install cPickle command says that such module doesn't exist!

Comment: 1 minute of searching and you would have recognized, that it's part of python. The only question now is which python to use. Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/742782/how-to-install-cpickle-on-python-3-4).